# Location isn't readable when picking document with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

> [Error: Location 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/DocumentPicker/68f6fec2-feff-48e1-a0cc-d8fe5f54bc0b.pdf' isn't readable.]

Getting this error when trying to read a file as base64 from expo DocumentPicker

Using expo sdk 48 and latest expo go app on **Android**, don't know on IOS

This is the code that I'm using:

```
const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
    type: "application/pdf",
    copyToCacheDirectory: true,
});

if (file.type === "cancel") return;

try {
    const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(file.uri, { encoding: "base64" });
    console.log(base64);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setErrorModal(true);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this as well, super frustrating that all of the sudden, it just stopped working on Android. I'll let you know if I find something that works!

Comment: I would suggest going back to expo sdk 47 for the time being as this is something new on sdk 48, still there's no solution to it even on the opened Github issue tracked in their official expo Github https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/21792.